# Jquery - slideDown message with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've form on my website with action wyslij.php. I want to send with ajax my php file "wyslij.php" but i don't know why it doesn't work.

Here's all form code to send:

```
form.on("submit", function(e) {
        var hasErrors = false;

        $('div.error_message').remove(); // Remove any old errors when submitting the form

        fields.each(function(i, elem) {
            var field = $(elem),
                empty = $.trim(field.val()) === "",
                errors = field.data("error");

            if (empty) {
                hasErrors = true;
                field.after('<div class="error_message">' + errors + '</div>'); // add new error messages
                field.toggleClass("form_error", empty);
            }
        });

        if (!hasErrors) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "../Strona/wyslij.php",
                type: 'GET',
            })
            .done(function() {
                console.log("success");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
            });


        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you include a `header` inside a function? I'm pretty sure it can't be called once you've already done almost anything, ie `echo`ing text, etc.

Comment: U mean inside function redirect i need to echo my text right ?

Comment: No, I mean that a) I have no idea what you're trying to do, and b) you are going about this the wrong way. You should really look into using [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), so you don't have to redirect anything.

Comment: yeah i was thinking about ajax

Comment: "i don't know why it doesn't work.". Look in your console and network tab for clues. Or examine the XHR object that can be provided as a parameter to the "fail" method, and which you're currently ignoring. In other words, use the tools available to you to do some very basic debugging, instead of throwing your hands up.

Comment: And why have you got `e.preventDefault();` in an `else`? What is being prevented here? A form submission? If that's the case, then if you don't call preventDefault in all cases the form will do a normal postback and never an ajax call, because the script won't have time to run before the page refreshes.

Comment: XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost/Strona/wyslij.php".

Comment: I've edited code for u

Comment: XHR failed...but with what status code and message? The network tab should show you if nothing else. And `e.preventDefault();` should be the first line of the function.

Comment: I had if there that check me the error variable, if havent errors do ajax function that i want to do and else prevent default i think its ok but only this XHR cant load correctly my php file, i let empty action on form and its success but in otherwise its returna fail message. I dont know what is wrong

Comment: like I said, check for errors in your console and/or network tab in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: yeah I fix that, e.preventDefault should be at the beggining and ajax is now running well